# CSS: limit number of lines when displaying multiple children

Tags: css, reactjs

I need to write the following in React:

1. A resizable container can have 0-10 children (with text), potentially varying length
2. The children can be wrapped in maximum 2 rows
3. If there is not enough space to display all the children, the longest children's text should be truncated with ellipses.

```
const css = { 
  border: "1px solid red", 
  margin: "4px",
  overflow: "hidden",
  textOverflow: "ellipsis",
  
  whiteSpace:"nowrap",
  padding: "2px",
  width: "100px" };

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexWrap: "wrap",
        overflowWrap: "anywhere",
        border: "1px solid green",
        maxHeight: "150px",
        overflow: "hidden",
      }}
    >
      <div style={css}>Long child</div>
      <div style={css}>child1</div>
      <div style={css}>child1</div>
      <div style={css}>child1</div>
      <div style={css}>child1</div>
      <div style={css}>child1</div>
      <div style={css}>child1</div>
      <div style={css}>child1</div>
      <div style={css}>child1</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is what I have so far, but not sure how to limit the display to 2 rows.

Comment: maybe you are looking for this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp ... but it's not a widely adopted solution. If css can't bring you there you may be forced to use a js solution measuring the computed height once the width is rendered with `getComputedStyle` and changing the actual text content dynamically. The issue is not the whole component.. it could be reduced to how to set the visibility of a div content as 2 rows only

Comment: Not sure Webkit helps in this case (I'd be okay to use it since it is covered by all major browsers).
I'd hate doing it programmatically, would expect some solution from CSS

Comment: there's no way to do it in css only using widely adopted standards yet. The `line-clamp` way I suggested before is not totally safe. Anyway if you want to cut it short, I can suggest you the clamp.js library that will be as easy as doing `[...document.querySelectorAll('.target')].forEach(target => {$clamp(target, {clamp: 2});`. I was going to post an answer using vanilla js but dealing with the `ResizeObserver` added lots of complexity especially to prevent infinite loops when the clamping retriggered the event